# How can I retrieve specific element from array using aggregation in Mongoose NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions, aggregation

So I have a code for the aggregation

```js
const documents = await deviceCollection
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        'readings.t': sensorType,
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$readings' },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        data: ['$readings.r', '$created_at'],
      },
    },
  ])
  .toArray();

return documents.map(({ data }) => data);
```

and I have a document structure like this one

```js
{
    "readings" : [ 
        {
            "t" : "temperature",
            "r" : 6
        }, 
        {
            "t" : "humidity",
            "r" : 66
        }
    ],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-02-24T09:45:09.858Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-02-24T09:45:09.858Z")
}
```

I need to aggregate `r` value and `created_at` as `UTC` number for a particular reading type in a date range.
For example, the expected output for `temperature` reading is:

```js
[
 [6, 1616061903204],
 [5.6, 1616061903204]
]
```

But the code returns this

```js
[
    [
        6,
        "2021-02-24T09:45:09.858Z"
    ],
    [
        66,
        "2021-02-24T09:45:09.858Z"
    ],
    [
        5.6,
        "2021-02-24T09:50:09.820Z"
    ],
    [
        68,
        "2021-02-24T09:50:09.820Z"
    ],
]
```

And it means that I get the `humidity` type value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` your condition
- `$unwind` deconstruct `readings` array
- `$match` again to filter `readings` object
- `$toLong` to convert ISO date format to timestamp
- `$group` by null and construct `readings` array in a single array

```
const documents = await deviceCollection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "readings.t": sensorType } },
  { $unwind: "$readings" },
  { $match: { "readings.t": sensorType } },
  {
    $project: {
      readings: [
        "$readings.r",
        { $toLong: "$created_at" }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      readings: { $push: "$readings" }
    }
  }
]).toArray();

return documents.length ? documents[0].readings : [];
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ekn8gphoWkc)

Comment: thanks, it works well, but when I add `created_at: { $gte: start_date, $lte: end_date },` in the match operator, I receive an empty array for some reason

Comment: the data from the request payload `    "date_range": {
        "start_date": "2021-02-24T09:45:09.858Z",
        "end_date": "2021-02-24T10:05:09.804Z"
    }`

Comment: you have to convert that date to date type in match `created_at: { $gte: new Date(start_date), $lte: new Date(end_date) }`